# how to remove overlays from mapview with index in osmdroid?

Tags: android-studio, osmdroid

I add my overlays to osmdroid mapview with index as below:

```
kmzOverlay.setName(fileName);
kmzFolderOverlay.add(kmzOverlay);
mapView.getOverlays().add(kmzId,kmzOverlay);
mapView.invalidate();
```

now when I want remove overlays with this code:

```
mapView.getOverlays().remove(index);
mapView.invalidate();
```

the overlays didn't remove from mapview.

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

When removing overlays from an **osmdroid MapView**, ensure that you are using the **correct index** for the overlay you want to remove. The index should match the position of the overlay in the overlays list.

So I think this should work:

```
mapView.getOverlays().remove(kmzId);
mapView.invalidate();
```

By directly using `kmzId` instead of a separate index variable, you can accurately target the overlay for removal. Make sure `kmzId` corresponds to the correct overlay you intend to remove.